# Python Azure function app github Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions

Trying to deploy to Azure Function app with github actions
The error I get:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5tcF.png)

My Config variables are set to:

- `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD: false`
- `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: false`
- `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: 0`

In the .yaml pipeline for functions-action set:

- `scm-do-build-during-deployment: false`
- `enable-oryx-build: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried deploying Python Function via Github Actions and it was successful, Refer below:-

My Python Function V2 [Github Repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/PyFuncv2) For Python Function V1 refer my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276661/unable-to-explain-why-my-python-based-azure-function-is-not-appearing-when-using/76277867#76277867)

My **github yaml pipeline:**-

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - siliconfuncapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11' 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write 

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_D0F74B57F2B045B5BC8B8494FB4C84C6 }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_2F1CE8D0C7B34809983E6F310DC66814 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_35BE8BB9D9374F79ABFD06397E18EB36 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'siliconfuncapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

My ***Function App settings***:-

```
AzureWebJobsStorage:DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconrg988a9c;AccountKey=xxxxxxx=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD:1
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION:~4
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME:python
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:1
```

[image]

Refer the Answers in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327652/error-with-github-action-deploy-to-azure-web-app) to get insights into your error.

Comment: ok, i deleted my configuration file, relinked git and it started working